# Update all divs if contained in $.ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that returns a load of html, with some divs.

Internet Explorer likes to return html comments as part of the result[i] loop. They don't have an id, so it complains that "object doesn't support this property or method".

If I delete the comments, IE works fine. However, comments are useful. I don't want to delete them.

Firefox works fine all the time.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ajaxUrl,
     async: async,
     success: function(result){
        //Cycling through result DOM
        for (i=0;i<$(result).length;i++) {
           $('#'+$(result)[i].id).html($(result)[i].innerHTML);
        }
     }
```

**Edit**:
This is some simplified html returned from the ajax request. I've turned off all the data to make it easier to debug.

```
<!-- this comment breaks everything -->
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_inner">
        <ul>
          <li class="first "><a href="http://localhost/onlinecatalogue/index.php/browse">Browse</a></li>
          <li class="nav_on"><a href="http://localhost/onlinecatalogue/index.php/search">Search</a></li>          
          <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/onlinecatalogue/index.php/contact">Contact</a></li>    


        </ul>

       <div id="simple_search">
          <form name="simpleform" action="search" method="post">
             <fieldset class="simple_search">
               <input class="simple_input grey" type="text" id="search_box" name="search_box" value="kelly"/>
               <input type="submit" class="k_button simple_button" value="Search" />
             </fieldset>
          </form>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="ajax"><div id="search_content">
   <div id="search_container">
   </div>
   <div id="results">
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the raw response of the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick hack, you could just check if `result[i].id` exists before doing anything.

```
if(tyepof result[i].id !== 'undefined' && result[i].id !== null)
  $('#'+$(result)[i].id).html($(result)[i].innerHTML);
```

But if you just give these results a parent element to latch onto, you can do better:

```
$('#parent').html(result);
```

You might have to futz with that, but you get the idea.

Comment: That first part doesn't seem to work - I'll investigate more.As for the 2nd, I've toyed with the idea, but the code will have a few different parents to update - and if I add another, I'll definitely forget to include it in that code!